# Adding new rows to table on clicking button in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am pretty new to jquery. I have the following code. Here I want to get new rows in the table by clicking the add button, but I can't get it.,

can someone tell me what mistake I have done here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$("#addrows").click(function () {
  if (document.getElementById("hiddenprice").value == "") {
    imagecounter = 4;
   } else {
   imagecounter = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hiddenprice").value) +1;
   }
  //imagecounter=4;     
  var newImageDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
   .attr("id", 'add_div' + imagecounter);
  newImageDiv.after().html('<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" 
  cellspacing="0" class="pdzn_tbl1" border="0">' +
  '<tr><td><input type="text" name="rollno<? $i ?>"/></td>' +
  '<td><input type="text" name="firstname<? $i ?>" /></td>' +
  '<td><input type="text" name="lastname<? $i ?>" /></td></tr></table>');

  newImageDiv.appendTo("#addgroup");
  $("tr:last").after(newImageDiv);
  document.getElementById("hiddenprice").value = imagecounter;
  imagecounter++;
});
</script>
<div class="common" style="width:1040px; -overflow-x:scroll; padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;">
  <table id="maintable" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pdzn_tbl1" border="#729111 1px solid" >
  <tr>  
    <th>Roll No</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
  <?php $t_row=3; for($i=1;$i<=$t_row;$i++) {   ?>
  <tr id="rows">
    <div> 
      <td><input type="text" name="rollno<? $i ?>"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="firstname<? $i ?>"/></td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="lastname<? $i ?>"/></td>
    </div>
  </tr>
  <? } ?>

  <div id="addgroup"> 
    <div id="add_div1"> </div>
  </div> 
  <table>
    <input type="button" name="add" value="+Add" id="addrows" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenprice" name="hiddenprice" value="3"/> 
  </table>
</div>
```

**Code Formatted & Edit**: Code alignments updated and removed unwanted style codes for better readability

Comment: Could you please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Do you want to append table to div on addrows button click ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[Sample DEMO for Adding new row](http://jsfiddle.net/bwHnq/12/)**

```
$("#addrows").click(function () {
     $("#mytable").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr>';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
});
```

Updated:
Here div close at wrong place, it should end before  tr close, may be thats the error

```
<tr id="rows">
<div style="padding-left: 5px"> 
<td style="padding:5px;" > <input type="text" name="rollno<? $i ?>"  /> </td>
<td style="padding:5px;"> <input type="text" name="firstname<? $i ?>" /> </td>
<td style="padding:5px;"> <input type="text" name="lastname<? $i ?>" /> </td>
</div> // right
</tr>
</div> // wrong
```

**[UPDATED DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/2HGdv/13/)**

Comment: As I click in a cell in demo 2 an additional row is added. So I cannot enter data without having a new row added for every cell I click.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

which gives the solution

```
$('#maintable tr:last').after('<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>');
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery) a solution with `after` is to be preferred over `append`.

### Notes

- Do not mix accessing DOM elements with `jquery` with the approach with `getElementById`.
- As you are using jQuery there is no need to do your own AJAX function.

### Demo code

http://jsfiddle.net/A5dT6/1/

Comment: You need to work on the whole setup. Do a simplified version first and then add the other features.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vYTr8/1/)

```
    $(function () {
        $("#addRows").click(function () {
            $("#maintable").append("<tr> <td> New Row</td> </tr>")
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

try the Below Code

```
 $("#addrows").click(function(){  $("#maintable").append("<tr> <td> Data Here</td> </tr>") });
```

Answer (score 1):

I contribute another solution with a sample append tr to table use `.after()` method and string `interpolation` for updating row index.

```
let rowIndex = 0;

$("#addrows").click(function () {

  $('#maintable tr:last').after(`<tr><td><input type="text" name="rollno${rowIndex++}"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="firstname${rowIndex++}"/></td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="lastname${rowIndex++}"/></td></tr>`);
});
```

```js
let rowIndex = 0;
  
$("#addrows").click(function () {
  
  $('#maintable tr:last').after(`<tr><td><input type="text" name="rollno${rowIndex++}"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="firstname${rowIndex++}"/></td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="lastname${rowIndex++}"/></td></tr>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="common" style="width:1040px; -overflow-x:scroll; padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;">
  <table id="maintable" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pdzn_tbl1" border="#729111 1px solid" >
  <tr>  
    <th>Roll No</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
 
  <div id="addgroup"> 
    <div id="add_div1"> </div>
  </div> 
  <table>
    <input type="button" name="add" value="+Add" id="addrows" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenprice" name="hiddenprice" value="3"/> 
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('#maintable tr:last').after('<tr><td style="padding:5px;"> Add_Content_Here </td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code add new row dynamically in table using jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   var indexValue = 0;
   function addRow(){
        var test ='<tr><td>a</td></tr>';
        $("#applyTable").append(test);
        }
      </script>
</head>
<div>
<table class="myTable" border="1px" align="center" style="width:100px;"  >
        <tbody id="applyTable"> 
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div > 
<input type="button" value="Add" border="1px" onclick="addRow()" /><br/><br/>
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry id and mainHead not need but applyTable is call function to table id and add new row.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is as you havent added the jQuery code to the file, I just see the following two script blocks:

```
<script src="resources/scripts/jquery.ui.effect.js"></script>
<script src="resources/scripts/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js"></script>
```

and they don't seem to be having raw jQuery.

Try adding the following line too.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i added this too but cant find result. think ter is other problem it seems,.